# Using Grok filter out UUID from path string and return path

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, grok, logz.io

Here is an example line of the Log I am trying to filter :

```
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://api0.api.sin/api/social/v1/owner/4b3b60f6-1a54-4fbc-87b5-cc44496a6dbf/feeds/notifications/unread/count
```

The result I am expecting is the following:

```
  {
  "message": [
    [
      "Request starting"
    ]
  ],
  "httpversion": [
    [
      "1.1"
    ]
  ],
  "BASE10NUM": [
    [
      "1.1"
    ]
  ],
  "verb": [
    [
      "GET"
    ]
  ],
  "request": [
    [
      "http://api0.api.sin/api/social/v1/owner/feeds/notifications/unread/count"
    ]
  ],
  "uuid": [
    [
      "4b3b60f6-1a54-4fbc-87b5-cc44496a6dbf"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I've tried using the following grok expression but the request is returned as 2 separate values.

```
%{DATA:message}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}) %{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}%{UUID:uuid}%{NOTSPACE:request}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may capture the parts before and after UUID into separate groups, then you can combine the two values into one field:

```
grok {
  match => {
    "message" => "%{DATA:message}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}) %{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request1}/%{UUID:uuid}%{NOTSPACE:request2}"
  }
}

mutate {
  add_field => {
    "request" => "%{request1}%{request2}"
  }
}
```

You may drop `request1` and `request2` later if you wish, too.

If you can't use `mutate`, you can only come up with an expression where `request` includes the UUID:

```
%{DATA:message}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}) %{WORD:verb} (?<request>.*?(?<UUID>[a-fA-F0-9]{8}(?:-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}){3}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12})\S*)
```

because **one can't match two disjoint strings of text into one capturing group**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I 'm using logzio and I don't have access to logstash's filters like mutate, I can only use grok to solve the problem if possible.

Comment: @NatanGirma You can't match two disjoint strings of text into one capturing group anyway, so you are stuck. You probably should issue a support ticket.

Comment: Okay thanks for your suggetion, I will contact the support team.

Comment: @NatanGirma I added a kind of a workaround with `request` containing UUID

Comment: I'm pretty new with regex, do you think it is possible to ignore the uuid part like you would ignore a substring in a string (example: I've seen in regex you can remove the substring "bb" from a string "abba" and capture "aa"

Comment: @NatanGirma **You can't match two *disjoint* strings of text into *one* capturing group**. You can't "skip" a part of  match in this scenario. You can't match and remove with regex either.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew How many techs you are expertise at? :)